# I want to write test case in jest for the function in my react tsx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs

in my Header.tsx

> function :

```
const mobileMenuToggle: toggleMobileMenu = () => setIsNavOpen((prev) => !prev);
```

> button where it is used:

```
     <button
        data-testid="hamburgerBtn"
        className="HAMBURGER-ICON space-y-2 px-5 "
        onClick={mobileMenuToggle}
      >
        <span className=""></span>
        <span className=""></span>
        <span className=""></span>
      </button>
```

> Header.test.tsx

```
test("hamburgerMenuToggle button called", () => {
const mockFunction = jest.fn();
render(
  <button onClick={mockFunction}>
    <span className=""></span>
    <span className=""></span>
    <span className=""></span>
  </button>
);
// expect(screen.getByRole("button")).toBeInTheDocument();
expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I tried to write testcase for it but don't know how to target it from my Header.tsx file

Answer (score -1):

you should use `fireEvent` and add `data-testid="hamburgerBtn"`

```js
export interface IHamburgerMenuToggleProps {
  onClick?: () => void;
}
const HamburgerMenuToggle = ({ onClick }: IHamburgerMenuToggleProps) => {
  return (
    <button
      data-testid="hamburgerBtn"
      className="HAMBURGER-ICON space-y-2 px-5 "
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      <span className="" />
      <span className="" />
      <span className="" />
    </button>
  );
};
export default HamburgerMenuToggle;

//tests
import {
      fireEvent,
      render
    } from "@testing-library/react";
import HamburgerMenuToggle from "./hamburgerMenuToggle";

test("hamburgerMenuToggle button called", () => {
  const mockFunction = jest.fn();
  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <button data-testid="hamburgerBtn" onClick={mockFunction}>
      <span className=""></span>
      <span className=""></span>
      <span className=""></span>
    </button>
  );
  const button = getByTestId("hamburgerBtn");
  fireEvent.click(button);
  expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

test("hamburgerMenuToggle button called using component", () => {
  const mockFunction = jest.fn();
  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <HamburgerMenuToggle onClick={mockFunction} />
  );
  const button = getByTestId("hamburgerBtn");
  fireEvent.click(button);
  expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: I don't know why is it failing!! Do you know the what could be the reason

Comment: What connection do you think `mockFunction` has to the component under test?

Comment: @AlishMadhukar updated and tested it passed now

Comment: @Ahmad Mock function doesn't have any connection with the component, so it is basically useless

Comment: @AlishMadhukar added another test, this one is connected with the component